# If subproject has dependency add another

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I have a multi-module project and I want to add another dependency automatically if a submodule contains a specific dependency.

So far I've added this on my root `build.gradle.kts`

```
subprojects {
    apply {
        plugin("java")
    }

    project.configurations.implementation.get().allDependencies.forEach {
        println(it.name)
    }
}
```

But it prints nothing. How can I get all dependencies implemented by a subproject and then another if it contains one already?

Thanks

Comment: Gradle supplies a lot of options for implementing something like this ([mutually exclusive dependencies](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_capability_conflict.html), [default dependencies](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/resolution_rules.html#sec:configuration_defaults),  [amending component metadata](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/component_metadata_rules.html#fixing_wrong_dependency_details)), but it's tough to figure out what the best might be. Could you add more about what problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: re: "if a submodule contains a specific dependency". Do you mean a project/module dependency or an external jar/lib dependency? Readers will try and recreate the problem but we need more info.